# Javascript image resize onclick

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to change size of image on my page by clicking on image and I created this, but it didn't work.So what I should change there.

In javasript

```
 function nowe()
    {
    document.getElementsByTagName(img).height="100"; 
    document.getElementsByTagName(img).width="100";
    }
```

In html

```
   <img src="zwinka2.jpg" alt="jaszczurka_zwinka"  onclick="nowe()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a play around and came up with this
 in HTML

```
<button onclick="Revert()">reset images</button>
<br/>
<img id="change" src="animal_1.jpg" width="100" height="100" onClick="Change()">
```

in javascript

```
Function Change()
{
document.getElementById("change").height="200";
document.getElementById("change").width="200";
}
Function Revert()
{
document.getElementById("change").height="100";
document.getElementById("change").width="100";
}
```